# IISExpress Recompilation after Javascript change

Tags: iis, iis-express

As the title suggests, my IISExpress will recompile everything if I make a change to any of the javascript (or css, cshtml or typescript files).  This means I have to wait 15 to 60 seconds to see a javascript change reflected in the browser.

It happens in both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.

I assume there's a configuration problem in Visual Studio, the project or IISExpress, but I have been unable to figure out what to change, or even where to start looking.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.